# Why do I get the "Bad question warning" when first posting here?

Tags: support, questions, post-ban

I was going to post a question and I got the "bad question ban" warning. I have searched my previous posts and it turns out I have never posted anything on this SE - could one of the moderators please check if there are any deleted posts that I simply forgot about? If there are no past posts - why do I get a warning then? I have OK rep on other Stack Exchanges.

Thank you for any suggestions on how to improve this SE.

Comment: You have two deleted posts from the end of 2015, [here](http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/205888/perfectly-aerodynamic-kitchen-range-hood) and [here](http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/222160/will-matter-vibrating-at-thz-frequencies-emit-light).

Comment: thanks. I didn't realize those had been deleted or that they gathered negative votes. I didn't think there was anything wrong with the second one. I took the first one and posted it on the engineering SE and it created a very useful discussion and got some upvotes. See [here](http://engineering.stackexchange.com/questions/5357/perfectly-aerodynamic-kitchen-range-hood)

Comment: what can I do so that questions I didn't realize would be inappropriate don't weigh down on my profile?

Comment: [See also](http://physics.stackexchange.com/help/question-bans).

Comment: @rob thanks. The link says to edit past questions. Would you have any tips on what to do in my case? Thank you!

Comment: @cheater You're not actually blocked from asking --- you got the warning, but you didn't get delayed --- so your situation will improve as you ask well-received questions.

Comment: @rob i realize but I would like to improve the old questions as well